# Capybara DayPickerInput selection?

Tags: capybara

Has anyone had any luck in figuring out how to use the react library https://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/input/

With Capybara/Selenium? Unfortunately it doesn't allow simply typing in the text such as MM/DD/YYYY like most date-pickers. This only allows mouse selection.

Or is specifically setting the value basically the only way to do so?

Comment: Do you have an example that shows the configuration you are using? - every example on the page you linked to has a text box where you can type in the date.

Comment: Well I did notice the element has `readonly` as an attribute within the element (not sure why, as im not super familiar with react). I imagine that's partially why I cannot type in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example which shows the actual configuration of react-day-picker you're dealing with it's impossible to say exactly what you need to do, but the general rule is if you are testing the sites functionality then do what a user would need to do.  In your case that may mean click on the forward/back month arrows until you get to the desired month, then click on the specific day element. Assuming the date you want to select is in the future (September 20, 2019) it would be something like

```
caption = find('.DayPicker-Caption')
until caption.has_text?('September 2019', wait: 0) do
  current_month = caption.text
  find('.DayPicker-NavButton--next').click
  # wait for month to change
  expect(caption).not_to have_text(current_month)
end
find('.DayPicker-Day', exact_text: '20').click
```

If you're not actually testing functionality (web scraping, etc) then you can use `execute_script` to call the react-day-picker JS API and set a specific date.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately after some recursive element searching I was able to find what I needed and it matches the above pretty well. Do I need the "text" option if Im using "exact_text" or is that not needed? Like so: `find('div.DayPicker-Day', text: '15', exact_text: true).click` ?

Comment: @msmith1114 `find('div.DayPicker-Day', text: '15', exact_text: true)` is the same as `find('div.DayPicker-Day', exact_text: '15')` - which will do the same as `find('div.DayPicker-Day', text: /\A15\z/)` - use whichever makes you happier

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!